# Connect mysql to website using php

Tags: mysql, php, database

How to connect my database wich is create in mysql in terminal?

Comment: You mention MySQL, website, PHP, and terminal, but we have no idea what exactly you want to do. In any case, this is not about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rephrase your question:

- if you need to connect via phpMyAdmin, you need to have it properly [properly configured](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)
- if you need to connect via command line you need either [MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/) or [MySQL Utilities](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/) (for older versions)

From command line you need to follow [these simple steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html). For (a well configured) phpMyAdmin you have to connect with known credentials (regularly without root) and choose a database.
https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Disable-Root-Login-in-PhpMyAdmin-1.png